# MVVM-Light: Is this the best way to validate and revert a value in the View?

Tags: validation, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, revert

In my View I have TextBoxes like this one:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tBoxShippingWeight" Text="{Binding ShippingWeight, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="Number" />
```

When the user enters a value I do a basic validation (not the focus of this question) and if that fails I use the System.Windows.MessageBox to notify the user of the proper params and revert the value back to the previous value, which is always valid because it either came from a default init value or was properly entered by the user. I ended up calling RaisePropertyChanged("ShippingWeight") inside the if statement that does the validation. If I put it in the catch statement, it never gets raised if the MessageBox is also called from there. Is this a reasonable way to do the reversion or is there something better? Here is the code from the ViewModel:

```
public string ShippingWeight
{
    get { return ShippingModel.ShippingWeight.ToString(); }
    set
    {
    if (ShippingModel.ShippingWeight.ToString() == value) return;

    var oldValue = ShippingModel.ShippingWeight;

    try
    {
        int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ShippingParams.ShippingWeightMin) > intValue || Convert.ToInt32(ShippingParams.ShippingWeightMax) < intValue)
        {
            // Revert back to previous value
            // NOTE: This has to be done here. If done in the catch statement, 
            // it will never run since the MessageBox interferes with it.
            RaisePropertyChanged("ShippingWeight");

            throw new Exception();
        }

        ShippingModel.ShippingWeight = intValue;

        RaisePropertyChanged("ShippingWeight", oldValue, Convert.ToDouble(value), true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Value must be a whole number between " + ShippingParams.ShippingWeightMin + " and " + ShippingParams.ShippingWeightMax);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the formatting fix!

Answer (score 1):

You could consider to implement [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx)

Use some private fields to store the old values when BeginEdit is called and use these values when validation fails or the user cancels the edit.

Comment: Interesting! I will definitely take a look at that more (just had a glimpse @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx). I'll have to see how that interacts with the rest of this code. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: The DataGrid 'knows' about this interface and uses it when available.